# Do I have a virus? Dialog keeps popping up

Tags: mojave

[image]

Any idea what these applications are? And any ideas on how I could stop this dialog from appearing every time I restart my computer? Thank you!

Comment: Hmm. Thats interesting. Quick Google Search shows no results. Go ahead and run a [Malwarebyes](https://www.malwarebytes.com) just to be sure. If that comes back clean (which it should) we can look into a more extensive search as to whats causing this issue. Additionally, does this occur on other users or just your user?  Does this occur in [Safe Boot](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201262)?

Comment: normally viruses do not ask for permission

Comment: @Buscar웃 *try. They try not to ask for permission.

Comment: it is just a decapitated app that lost its name

Comment: run `launchctl list` in Terminal then report all that do not start with `com.apple`